# Flask-login session ID handling

Tags: flask-login

I am new in developing an web application with Flask and Flask-login. My app needs the user to login in order to utilize the functions in my web app. Since I am using Flask-login, do I have to handle the sessions like session ID..etc and how should I handle it?

Thanks,
Jo

Answer (score 1):

No, Flask-login helps you to manage login, logout and persisting your users' sessions over extended periods of time. There are great examples in helping to bootstrap your new application from the documentation.

[Documentation Reference](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[Full blown application example](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But let's say if 3 users login at the same time, is there a way to get the user session id for each user?

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to get a list of online users' id? Generally you should not care about the session id since they are short-lived. The session objects are handled within flask-login and should not be accessed outside the users' session.

Comment: What I mean is if there are a few login users to my application and access their own user's dashboard and retrieve some data from API, I have an API class to retrieve the data for the user, how can my API class handle with different users with different sessions?

Comment: I think you may want to spend time going through the full blown application example I referred in my answer. I saw that you have asked a few questions related to flask and most of them are actually answered with actual example there.