# python flask - entering exact url bypasses login screen

Tags: python, html, authentication, flask

I've got a program with consists of a login screen and then a home page. When a user inputs the correct details, they are redirected to their home page with the path `localhost:5000/Home/<user>`. The problem is that if I then type this url with the correct username, I can bypass the login screen. I've tried this in a private browser in case the issue was cache, but the issue is still there.  It makes sense, but I can't find a solution for this issue and the same doesn't occur on any website that I visit. Any ideas? My webapps code:

```
#imports
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template, session
import hashlib
import os
from os.path import exists

#declaring app with html template folder
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='template')

#Redirects if user goes to base url


@app.route('/')
def gotomenu():
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

#renders Login.html


@app.route('/Login')
def login():
    return render_template('Login.html', error=error)


error = None


@app.route('/AdminHome/AddUser')
def adduser():
    return "add a new user"


@app.route('/Login/Verify', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def verifyuser():
    #Gets username and passtword from login.html
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['un']
        password = request.form['pw']
    else:
        username = request.args.get('un')
        password = request.args.get('pw')
    #Checks if user exists
    filename = (str(username) + str('.txt'))
    if exists(filename):
        #Get stored password hash and input password hash for compare
        encodedpassword = password.encode('utf-8')
        hashedpassword = hashlib.sha256(encodedpassword).digest()
        file = open(filename, 'r+')
        checkhashedpassword = file.read()
        checkhashedpassword.strip()
        file.close()
        #checks if password is correct
        if str(hashedpassword) == str(checkhashedpassword):
            filename = (str(username) + str('Status') + str('.txt'))
            file = open(filename, 'r+')
            status = file.read().strip()
            file.close()
            #redirects user depending on their user type
            if status == "admin":
                return redirect(url_for('adminhome', user=username))
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('userhome', user=username))
        else:
            error = "Invalid credentials"
            return render_template('Login.html', error=error)
    else:
        error = "Invalid credentials"
        return render_template('Login.html', error=error)

#displays home for admin


@app.route('/AdminHome/<user>')
def adminhome(user):
    return render_template('admin.html')

#displays home for standard user


@app.route('/UserHome/<user>')
def userhome(user):
    return 'Welcome %s' % user

#displays error message


@app.route('/Login/Error')
def UnknownUser():
    return render_template('nosuchuser.html')


#running app
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JusDrive</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Login to access JusDrive services">
    </head>
      <style>
        h1 {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            color: #2f2d2d;
            text-align: Center;
        }
        p {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            text-align: Center;
            color: #2f2d2d;
        }
      </style>
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align: center;"><strong>JusDrive</strong></h1>
  <p style="text-align: center;">Welcome to JusDrive school of motoring, to get started, you must sign in first:</p>
  <form action = "http://localhost:5000/Login/Verify" method = "post">
    <p>Enter Username: </p>
    <p><input type = "text" name = "un" /></p>
    <p>Enter Password: </p>
    <p><input type = "password" name = "pw" /></p>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "submit" /></p>
  </form>
  {% if error %}
    <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{ error }}
  {% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

admin.html:

```
<style>
  h1 {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #2f2d2d;
      text-align: Center;
  }
  p {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      text-align: Center;
      color: #2f2d2d;
  }
</style>

<p style="text-align: center;"><img src="https://d3nqfz2gm66yqg.cloudfront.net/images/v1459953958-arx7xigg2x80clheksy9.png" alt="Admin" width="516" height="306" /></p>
<p><a title="Add a user" href="http://localhost:5000/AdminHome/AddUser" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Add User</a></p>
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: You import `session`, but don't seem to use it for anything. Web sites usually track the logged-in/not-logged-in status of a client in session data, and check it before handling any request. If a client is not logged in, they're redirected to the login page.

Comment: Ever heard of Cookies ? Try that

Comment: Flask seems to have a dedicated package for this, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67814503/7916438

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a function that checks if user is logged in
2. 'decorate' all your routes which require user login with this function. 'Decorate' loosely means apply this function over another function or more technically - A decorator is a function that wraps and replaces another function.

See worked example [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/0.12.x/patterns/viewdecorators/)